# Gráfico com rolagem horizontal c#

Tags: c#, gráfico

Bom dia galera, estou desenhando um gráfico de linha em uma pictureBox com "drawline"s concatenados.

Basicamente o que eu desejo é criar uma barra de rolagem horizontal para navegar pelo gráfico, ou seja, poder percorrer todo gráfico na horizontal usando a barra de rolagem. Segue código que desenha o gráfico.

```
    void DrawANALISE()
    {
        Graphics g = pcbANALISE.CreateGraphics();
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        var lastPoint1 = new PointF(0F, (float)(2 * Height / 5) * 0.5F);
        PointF newPoint1 = new PointF();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i++)
        {
            //aquisicaodata é uma lista onde há 6000 valores para y
            var porcent = aquisicaodata[i] / 5;
            newPoint1.X = (i + 1) * 0.2f;

            if (porcent > 1) porcent = 1;
            var hg = porcent * (2 * pcbANALISE.Height / 5);

            if (porcent >= 1) newPoint1.Y = 2 * pcbANALISE.Height / 5 - hg;
            else newPoint1.Y = 2 * pcbANALISE.Height / 5 - hg - 1;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) g.DrawLine(p, lastPoint1, newPoint1);

            lastPoint1 = newPoint1;
        }
    }
```

Como no código estou desenhando 1 ponto a cada 0.2 pixels na horizontal e há um total de 6000 pontos, o que resultaria em um total de 1200 pixels na horizontal para desenhar todo gráfico, uma pcb de 500 pixels de largura não é suficiente para exibir todo gráfico. Por isso gostaria de criar uma barra de rolagem horizontal para poder ter a visualização de todo gráfico. Editarei se necessário. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta criar uma variável de controle para a câmera scrollbar:

```
int camera = 0;
```

Neste trecho ficaria assim:

```
for (int i = camera; i < (camera + (pictureBox.Width / 0.2)); i++)
```

e no evento do scrollbar:

```
hscrollBar_scroll(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    camera = hScrollBar.Value * 6000 / 100;
    DrawANALISE();//esqueci de por para redesenhar o gráfico.
}
```

Se com isso não consegui lhe ajudar posso fazer um controle completo, se preferir.

Comment: Valeu pela atenção novamente Weiner, então amigo, eu fiz aqui desse jeito mas não funcionou a rolagem. Mexo a scrollbar mas o gráfico continua parado.

Comment: se puder continuar ajudando ficaria muito satisfeito.

Comment: Só adicione o método para redesenhar no scrollbar, eu havia esquecido.

Comment: Amigo, até funciona a rolagem dessa maneira, porém o gráfico fica realmente se redesenhando desde o inicio a cada tick da rolagem, o que faz cair muito o desempenho, se eu clico pra deslocar o grafico o programa fica um pouco travado.

Comment: Agora não quer atualizar haha, mostrar o seguinte erro: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'O objeto está sendo usado em outro lugar.".

Comment: e aponta para a seguinte linha : using (var p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 0.1f)) g.DrawLine(p, lastPoint2, newPoint2);

Comment: vou tentar fazer um controle aki para lhe ajudar, mas realmente vc tem a necessidade de desenhar 10 valores em um único pixel, pq axo que nem está sendo mostrado todos esses valores.

Comment: Para a minha aplicação eu necessito de 300 pontos em um segundo amigo

Comment: será que não esta sendo mostrado? poxa, se não estiver to perdendo desempenho atoa

Comment: se você puder fazer esse controle eu agradeço, tentei de várias maneiras porém sem êxito.

Comment: cara, não sei se você sabe me responder isso, mas você sabe se para uma aplicação de visualização e análise de gráfico, com interface para usuários seria melhor usar c# ou java? Não tenho muito conhecimento na área ainda. Creio que os dois são parecidos.